# CashRegister function logic missing 1 iteration in while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm a building a cash register function, which is almost done , I'm just missing a very very small detail.

I just need the following loop to give one more iteration before it stops to add 1 more penny to my array and complete the exercise  but I don't see what I'm missing in my stop condition or how to change it without ruining what I've done.

```
    for(let i = (cid.length-1); i >= 0; i--)
    {      
      while(counter <= troco)
        {         
          if(valorMaximo > cid[i][1] || (counter + coinsValue[cid[i][0]]) > troco ) // problem could be here
            break;

          valorMaximo += coinsValue[cid[i][0]]
          counter += coinsValue[cid[i][0]]
        }
      cid[i][1] = valorMaximo;
      valorMaximo = 0;
      if(counter > troco || cid[i][1] == 0)
        cid.splice(i, 1)
    }
```

The expected output :

```
{status: "OPEN", change: [["TWENTY", 60], ["TEN", 20], ["FIVE", 15], ["ONE", 1], ["QUARTER", 0.5], ["DIME", 0.2], ["PENNY", 0.04]]}
```

The actual output :

```
{status: "OPEN", change: [["TWENTY", 60], ["TEN", 20], ["FIVE", 15], ["ONE", 1], ["QUARTER", 0.5], ["DIME", 0.2], ["PENNY", 0.03]]}
```

The code is part of a larger function , if you wanna look :

Function takes purchase price as the first argument (price), payment as the second argument (cash), and cash-in-drawer (cid) as the third argument.

```js
let coinsValue = {
  "PENNY": 0.01,
  "NICKEL": 0.05,
  "DIME": 0.1,
  "QUARTER": 0.25,
  "ONE": 1,
  "FIVE": 5,
  "TEN": 10,
  "TWENTY": 20,
  "ONE HUNDRED": 100
}

function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {

  let troco = cash - price
  let dinheiroEmCaixa = 0;
  let change = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < cid.length; i++)
    dinheiroEmCaixa += cid[i][1]

  if (dinheiroEmCaixa < troco)
    return change = {
      status: 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS',
      change: []
    };

  if (dinheiroEmCaixa == troco)
    return change = {
      status: "CLOSED",
      change: cid
    }

  if (dinheiroEmCaixa > troco) {
    let availableToGive = 0; //we can only give notes or coins below channge value
    let valorMaximo = 0; //set limit to the sum of coins if there are no more coins
    let counter = 0; //will count the sum of the coins we have

    for (let i = 0; i < cid.length; i++) {
      if (coinsValue[cid[i][0]] > troco)
        cid.splice(i)
      else if (coinsValue[cid[i][0]] < troco && cid[i][1] > 0)
        availableToGive += cid[i][1]
    }

    if (availableToGive < troco)
      return change = {
        status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS",
        change: []
      }

    for (let i = (cid.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
      while (counter <= troco) {
        if (valorMaximo > cid[i][1] || (counter + coinsValue[cid[i][0]]) > troco)
          break;

        valorMaximo += coinsValue[cid[i][0]]
        counter += coinsValue[cid[i][0]]
      }
      cid[i][1] = valorMaximo;
      valorMaximo = 0;
      if (counter > troco || cid[i][1] == 0)
        cid.splice(i, 1)
    }
    return change = {
      status: "OPEN",
      change: cid
    }
  }
}

console.log(checkCashRegister(3.26, 100, [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
]))
```

If anyone could help me out would be great, I have been on this for some time.

Comment: @CharlesEF Array indexes go from 0 to length-1, so that would access outside the array.

Comment: Don't use floating point for money. It can't represent most decimal fractions exactly, and the errors that are introduced can cause problems like this. Instead of operating in dollars, make everything integer number of pennies.

Comment: When you're done you can divide by 100 and round to 2 decimal places to show it in dollar values.

Comment: That's a good sugestion ! Thanks